# How to replace characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string like

```
var content = '<img id="product-collection-image-515" src="http://www.dressbd.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x300/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/u/shirt.jpg" alt="Shirt"></img>';
```

I would like to change it like below.

```
var content = '<img id="product-collection-image-515" src="https://www.dressbd.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x300/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/u/shirt.jpg" alt="Shirt"></img>';
```

I would like to replace 'http' with 'https' using JavaScript. I used `.replace()`, but it is not working.

How can I do that ?? Thanks

Comment: In your question you mentioned that you used the `.replace()` function and this didn't work but you forgot to show us your code. So it's kind of hard to tell what you might have done wrong.

Comment: can you provide the whole code to check because replace() normally use for this task

Comment: Don't use regexp to modify HTML. Instead, if the HTML is in the DOM, modify the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

Comment: @torazaburo, actually this HTML is coming as plain string. If I use `typrof` to `content`, I am getting `string`. I think here is the issue. I have to do something special here.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the string? If you plan to insert it into the DOM, then insert it, then modify it using standard DOM functions such as `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use `.split()`
For example `.split("//")`

```
var p = content.split("//");
p[0] += "s";
var result = p[0] + p[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this you mean? Works as `replace()` should

```js
var content = '<img id="product-collection-image-515" src="http://www.dressbd.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x300/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/u/shirt.jpg" alt="Shirt"></img>';

var newContent = content.replace('http','https');

alert(newContent)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working.

Comment: Click the button above `Run code snippet` you'll see an alert with the URL using `https` - if it's not working for you then something else is wrong

Comment: @Erik-JanWestendorp Please stop suggesting edits which add newlines inside string literals. That is not valid in JS. I rollbacked the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var str = "Hi William How are You?",
    res = str.replace("William", "Anderson");
alert(res);
```

The result will be:

```
Hi Anderson How are You?
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the replace function didn't work for you, its likely that you didn't assign the return value to a new variable.

E.g. you cant just do this:

```
content.replace('http','https')
```

Since that function **returns** the result and doesnt actually change the 'content' string.

Instead you need to do this:

```
var newvar = content.replace('http','https');
```

However, you may not need any code at all.

Using // in front of urls will instruct the browser to use the same protocol as the current page. Eg if viewing from

```
https://example.com/mypage
```

this link

```
//google.com/somestuff.js
```

is requested as

```
https://google.com/somestuff.js
```

whereas if you are on a plain http site, the link will be requested as

```
http://google.com/somestuff.js
```

If you try to load mixed content (http and https) into a page, browsers will complain about security issues, so its always best to use the // format.